# images with width: 100% in table cells don't scale right in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a 3-column table which contains images. All td's have `width="33%"`, and the images contained have CSS `width:100%`. In FF and Opera, the images scale like I want them to, i.e. fill the entire width of the cell, maintaining their aspect ratio. However, in IE7, they behave quite differently: I think the pic with the largest width stretches the entire column, and the smaller ones are stretched up to the new available width.

The page in question is: http://mybgagent.com/print.php?offers_id=4515

*(I know the site is a mess, I didn't code it)*

Any advice on what to do? Setting css `position:absolute` makes images scale correctly in IE, but breaks scaling in Opera and FF, as well as positioning in all browsers.

Comment: It is not a good idea to let the browser scale any pictures. Some browsers are really not good in doing this (quality). I would prefer to leave the pictures in their original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a solution for each browser but no way to target it, well here comes the [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) to help you with that! Just plug in this jQuery to your site (in the `<head>` section), then write separate rules for IE and the real browsers and append `.ie` before your IE selectors :)

Works great, I use it all the time!

Example:

```
myTd
{
   background: #f00; /*whatever your rules are*/
}

.ie .myTdv
{
   position: absolute;
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: Thanks, will do. However, I'm still looking for the solution for IE. And, r isn't a hex digit :P

Comment: Looking back on this one year later, I've now learned enough that this is just another one of IE's bugs and oddities, and should either be avoided or a complex workaround be devised using what you suggested. Lazy bastard that I am, I picked the first option.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue a lot with IE7 "compatibility" mode. the easy fix was to not only put

```
width: 100%;
```

in my css, but also

```
width: 100%;
float: left;
```

cleared that nasty hiccup right up.

Comment: on what element did you place the float: left and width: 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the style of the parent cell to `position:relative`.

Comment: Tried that, and then added position:absolute for the images, too. Didn't work.